# AWS DynamoDB ExclusiveStartKey default value

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to make a query to DynamoDB, and if a `LastEvaluatedKey` is returned (meaning the query exceeds 1 MB) I want to make other queries in order to fetch all the required data from the table, using `LastEvaluatedKey` as `ExclusiveStartKey` for the next query.
This is the code I have for now:

```
query_response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('brand').eq(brand)
)

pagination_key = None

if 'LastEvaluatedKey' in query_response:
    pagination_key = query_response['LastEvaluatedKey']

    while pagination_key:
        next_query_response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('brand').eq(brand),
            ExclusiveStartKey=pagination_key
        )
```

However, I'd like to refacto this code by extracting the query into a method, passing it pagination_key as an argument. To do this, I'd have to be able to either set `ExclusiveStartKey` to `False`, `None` or some other default value for the first call but I didn't find anything on this, or I'd have to be able to exclude the `ExclusiveStartKey` alltogether, but I don't know how to do this either.

Comment: I know you can simply omit the ExclusiveStartKey or set it to null in the java sdk. Have you tried simply omitting that argument or setting it to None? What were your results?

Comment: Setting the key to `None` throws an Exception: `Invalid type for parameter ExclusiveStartKey, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy way of building the parameters:

> ```
> query_params = { 'KeyConditionExpression': Key('brand').eq(brand) }
>
> if pagination_key:
>     query_params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = pagination_key
>
> query_response = table.query(query_params)
> ```

Comment: I had to add ** prefix to the argument on the last line like this  `query_response = table.query(**query_params)`

Comment: I added ** kwarg param but you are in the right direction

Answer (score 8):

Using keyword Arguments `**kwargs` it might look like this. Also, 
I am setting up the query before and only updating the `ExclusiveStartKey`every time.

```
query = { "KeyConditionExpression": Key('brand').eq(brand) }


ExclusiveStartKey = None
while True:
    if ExclusiveStartKey is not None:
        query['ExclusiveStartKey'] = ExclusiveStartKey
    query_response = table.query(**query)

    if 'LastEvaluatedKey' in query_response:
        ExclusiveStartKey = query_response['LastEvaluatedKey']
    else:
        break
```